# htmlTTF File from Google FOnts doesnt work how can i fix this?

Tags: html, css, font-face, bootstrap-5, truetype

I don't know what's the problem, is it the quotation or is it something else? My code is below I use Bootstrap Heading tag and the id is "title", please help me out, thank you in advance

what seems to be the problem?

here is my code:

```
 @font-face {
        font-family: 'Heebo-Regular';
        src: url("res/fonts/Heebo/Heebo-Regular.ttf");
    }
    
    #title {
        font-family: 'Heebo-Regular';
    }
```

Comment: Probably the path is incorrec, check in your browser console if you have a 404 regarding the font file

Comment: As @Sfili_81 suggests, check that you have got the font stored correctly on your system. I have just used Heebo regular direct from google fonts and it works fine so you could try that as a test. See https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Heebo?query=Heebo

Comment: src: url('../res/fonts/Heebo/Heebo-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'); I found the porblem thank youu